# Swift Vapor - 'Cannot invoke 'add' with an argument list of type...' errors in configure.swift

Tags: swift, vapor, leaf

I am doing an e-commerce tutorial from Paul Hudson on YouTube. I am getting following errors in `configure.swift`:

```swift
import FluentSQLite
import Vapor
import Leaf // added
/// Called before your application initializes.
public func configure(_ config: inout Config, _ env: inout Environment, _ services: inout Services) throws {
    // Register providers first
    try services.register(FluentSQLiteProvider())

    // Register routes to the router
    let router = EngineRouter.default()
    try routes(router)
    services.register(router, as: Router.self)

    // Register middleware
    var middlewares = MiddlewareConfig() // Create _empty_ middleware config
    // middlewares.use(FileMiddleware.self) // Serves files from `Public/` directory
    middlewares.use(ErrorMiddleware.self) // Catches errors and converts to HTTP response
    services.register(middlewares)

    // Configure a SQLite database
    let sqlite = try SQLiteDatabase(storage: .memory)
    // Register the configured SQLite database to the database config.
    var databases = DatabasesConfig()
    databases.add(database: sqlite, as: .sqlite)
    services.register(databases)

    // Configure migrations
    var migrations = MigrationConfig()
    migrations.add(model: Todo.self, database: .sqlite)
    services.register(migrations)
    let leafProvider = LeafProvider()    // added
    try services.register(leafProvider)  // added
    config.prefer(LeafRenderer.self, for: ViewRenderer.self)// added
      // http://localhost:8080/ already in use so adding new server http://localhost:8080/ below -
    let serverConfigure = NIOServerConfig.default(hostname: "0.0.0.0", port: 9090)
    services.register(serverConfigure)

    let directoryConfig = DirectoryConfig.detect()
    services.register(directoryConfig)
    try services.register(FluentSQLiteProvider())
    var databaseConfig = DatabasesConfig()
    let db =    try SQLiteDatabase(storage: .file(path:   "\(directoryConfig.workDir)pizza.db"))
     databaseConfig.add(model: db, database: as .sqlite)
    /**
    The line just above shows errors - 
    errror 1 -> Cannot invoke 'add' with an argument list of type '(model:      
    SQLiteDatabase)'
    error 2 -> Expected expression in list of expressions 
    */       
    services.register(databaseConfig)
    var migrationConfig =  MigrationConfig()
    migrationConfig.add(model: pizza.self,  database: sqlite)
    /**
    The line just above shows error -> Cannot invoke 'add' with an argument list of type     '(model: pizza.Type, database: SQLiteDatabase)'
    */
    services.register(migrationConfig)
} 
// configure.swift ends here
```

I am also pasting my Package.swift code for reference -

```
 // swift-tools-version:4.0

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
name: "vv",
products: [
    .library(name: "vv", targets: ["App"]),
],
dependencies: [
    //  A server-side Swift web framework.
    .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/vapor.git", from: "3.0.0"),

    //  Swift ORM (queries, models, relations, etc) built on SQLite 3.
    .package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/fluent-sqlite.git", from: "3.0.0"),
.package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/leaf.git", from: "3.0.0"),
],
targets: [
    .target(name: "App", dependencies: ["Leaf", "Vapor","FluentSQLite"]),
 .target(name: "Run", dependencies: ["App"]),
    .testTarget(name: "AppTests", dependencies: ["App"])
]
)
```

pizza.swift file -

```
 import Foundation
 import Vapor
 import FluentSQLite

 struct pizza: Encodable, Content, Decodable, SQLiteModel {
     var id:  Int?
     var name: String
     var description: String
     var  price: Int
 }
```

I am unable to figure out what the above errors mean! Thanks.

routes.swift file -

```
import Routing
import Vapor
import FluentSQLite

public func routes(_ router: Router) throws {
router.get { req -> Future <View> in
let Newyorker = Pizza(id: 5, name: "statinisland", description: "impracticaljokers", price: 55)
    let Traditional = Pizza(id: 5, name: "rome", description: "pope", price: 55)
    return try req.view().render("welcome",["pizza":[Newyorker,Traditional]])
}

 router.post(Pizza.self, at: "add") { req, pizza ->
     Future<Response> in
    return Pizza.save(on:req).map(to:Response.self) {Pizza
        in
        return req.redirect(to: "/")
    }
   }
/*Error - Type 'Pizza' has no member 'save'; did you mean 'name'?
 Replace 'save' with 'name' */  
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a re-write of my original answer to address all the issues:

`configure.swift`

1. Don't define multiple instances of `MigrationConfig()` and `DatabaseConfig()`.
2. Grouping related tasks (e.g. adding models) together will make your code easier to debug and maintain.
3. You have added two instances of `.sqlite` databases.
4. You omitted the `.` in `.sqlite` when you were adding the `pizza` model.

So, the relevant part of your configure.swift becomes:

```
let directoryConfig = DirectoryConfig.detect()
services.register(directoryConfig)
let sqlite = try SQLiteDatabase(storage: .file(path:   "\(directoryConfig.workDir)pizza.db"))
// Register the configured SQLite database to the database config.
var databases = DatabasesConfig()
databases.add(database: sqlite, as: .sqlite)
services.register(databases)

var migrations = MigrationConfig()
migrations.add(model: Todo.self, database: .sqlite)
migrations.add(model: Pizza.self,  database: .sqlite)
services.register(migrations)
```

`pizza.swift`:

1. I prefer using `final class` rather than a `struct` as it gives you more flexibility (e.g. in your initialisers).
2. You need to make it conform to the `Migration`.

So, a minimal `Pizza` model becomes:

```
final class Pizza:SQLiteModel {
    var id:  Int?
    var name: String
    var description: String
    var  price: Int

    init(id: Int? = nil, name: String, desc:String, price:Int)
    {
        self.id = id
        self.description = desc
        self.name = name
        self.price = price
    }
 }

extension Pizza: Migration { }
```

For completeness, your configure.swift becomes:

```
import FluentSQLite
import Vapor
import Leaf // added
public func configure(_ config: inout Config, _ env: inout Environment, _ services: inout Services) throws {
    // Register providers first
    try services.register(FluentSQLiteProvider())

    // Register routes to the router
    let router = EngineRouter.default()
    try routes(router)
    services.register(router, as: Router.self)

    // Register middleware
    var middlewares = MiddlewareConfig() // Create _empty_ middleware config
    // middlewares.use(FileMiddleware.self) // Serves files from `Public/` directory
    middlewares.use(ErrorMiddleware.self) // Catches errors and converts to HTTP response
    services.register(middlewares)

    let directoryConfig = DirectoryConfig.detect()
    services.register(directoryConfig)
    let sqlite = try SQLiteDatabase(storage: .file(path:"\(directoryConfig.workDir)pizza.db"))
    var databases = DatabasesConfig()
    databases.add(database: sqlite, as: .sqlite)
    services.register(databases)

    var migrations = MigrationConfig()
    migrations.add(model: Todo.self, database: .sqlite)
    migrations.add(model: Pizza.self, database: .sqlite)
    services.register(migrations)

    let leafProvider = LeafProvider()    // added
    try services.register(leafProvider)  // added
    config.prefer(LeafRenderer.self, for: ViewRenderer.self)// added
    let serverConfigure = NIOServerConfig.default(hostname: "0.0.0.0", port: 9090)
    services.register(serverConfigure)
}
```

Comment: I did as you directed. The first two errors. didn't go away, and the last error changed to "Expression type '()' is ambiguous without more context"

Comment: "EDIT - just noticed you have added two databases, both with identifier .sqlite, one in memory, the other in a file. This isn't going to work." - by "the other in a file" - I guess its configure.swift file, what do you mean by "one in memory" ?

Comment: also added "Migration", which by mistake I had forgotten and also made it final class. so its now "final class pizza: Encodable, Content, Decodable, SQLiteModel, Migration {". Now the last error is gone. First 2 errors still remain.

Comment: pardon me, but what how to rectify it ?

Comment: I posted the whole configure.swift an hour ago.

Comment: i) In configure.swift, I had to comment-out  the "migrations.add(model: Pizza.self,  database: .sqlite)" step to make it work. I left the pizza.swift file as struct for the time-being. iii)  I am still getting errors in routes.swift. Posting routes.swift file above.

Comment: This is a separate issue. Please post as a different question. With the errors.

Comment: OK. Sure will do.

Comment: done that. Now please look into the matter, when free